# How to get DOM or jQuery element by mouse coordinates?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When mouse coordinates in a web page is given, how can we catch hold of the DOM or jQuery element at that given position?

For example, at a known position x=320 and y=80, how to get whatever DOM element present at this position?